# How to use relative imports in both, module and main

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have the following setup of a library in python:

```
library
  | - __init__.py
  | - lib1.py
  | - ...
  | - tools
        | - __init__.py
        | - testlib1.py
```

so in other words, the directory `library` contain python modules and the directory `tools`, which is a subdirectory of `library` contains e.g. one file `testlib1.py`to test  the library `lib1.py`.

`testlib1.py` therefore need to import `lib1.py` from the directory above to do some tests etc., just by calling `python testlib1.py` from somewhere on the computer, assuming the file is in the search path. 
In addition, I only want ONE `PYTHONPATH` to be specified.

But we all know the following idea for `testlib1.py` does not work because the relative import does not work:

```
from .. import lib1
...
do something with lib1
```

I accept two kind of answers:

1. An answer which describes how still to be possible to call `testlib1.py` directly as the executing python script.
2. An answer that explains a better conceptual setup of of the modules etc, with the premise that everything has to be in the directory `project` and the tools has to be in a *different* directory than the actual libraries.

If something is not clear I suggest to ask and I will update the question.

Comment: Does your one `PYTHONPATH` include the parent directory of `library/`?

Comment: @tom: Yes, so for example, to import `lib1.py` in some other, unrelated file I do `from library import lib1`.

Comment: If `library/` is in your `PYTHONPATH`, then you should just import `lib` absolutely from your test module. i.e. `from library import lib1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a solution, which does

1. works with the current implementation
2. does not require any changes in `PYTHONPATH`
3. without the need to hardcode the top-lebel directory

In `testlib1.py` the following code will do (has been tested):

```
import os
import sys
dirparts = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).split('/')
sys.path.append('/'.join(dirparts[:-1]))

import  mylib1
```

Not exactly sure this is a very clean or straightforward solution, but it allows to import any module from the directory one level up, which is what I need (as the test code or extra code or whetever is always located one level below the actual module files).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `__init__.py` to the `tools` directory. The relative import should work.

Comment: Not it does not. I cut it back in the question.

Comment: Oh, you also have to run testlib1 as a package -- like this: python -m library.tools.testlib1

Comment: This also is not a solution: I require `testlib1.py` to be run from ANYWHERE in my system without going into this directory. When I try to do this as you suggested I get an error `/usr/bin/python: No module named testrunner`. Also please see updated question regarding PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you plan to use relative imports then you *can't* run the module by itself.
Either drop the relative imports or drop the idea of running `testlib1.py` directly.

Also I believe a test file should never use relative imports. Test should check whether the library works, and thus the code should be as similar as possible to the code that the users would actually use. And usually users do not add files to the library to use relative imports but use absolute imports.

By the way, I think your file organization is too much "java-like": mixing source code and tests. If you want to do tests then why not have something like:

```
project/
   |
   +-- src/
   |    |
   |    +--library/
   |    |     |
   |    |     +- lib1.py
   |    |     |
   |    |    #...
   |    +--library2/ #etc.
   |
   +-- tests/
        |
        +--testlibrary/
        |      |
        |      +- testlib1.py
        #etc
```

To run the tests just use a tool like `nosetests` which automatically looks for this kind of folder structure and provide tons of options to change the search/test settings.